# React js react-responsive-carousel not loading with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-responsive-carousel

I am using React Responsive Carousel for my project, but I am getting this error in console

```
ROR in ./node_modules/react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css 1:0
```

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> .carousel .control-arrow,.carousel.carousel-slider .control-arrow{-webkit-transition:all .25s ease-in;-moz-transition:all .25s ease-in;-ms-transition:all .25s ease-in;-o-transition:all .25s ease-in;transition:all .25s ease-in;opacity:.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);position:absolute;z-index:2;top:20px;background:none;border:0;font-size:32px;cursor:pointer}.carousel .control-arrow:hover{opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100)}.carousel .control-arrow:before,.carousel.carousel-slider .control-arrow:before{margin:0 5px;display:inline-block;border-top:8px solid transparent;border-botto

My webpack configuration is:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

const rootPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: path.join(rootPath, 'index.html'),
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /^(?!.*\.spec\.js$).*\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
          {
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            options: {
              quiet: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2|woff)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loaders: ['url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff&name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'],
        include: /fonts/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loaders: ['url-loader?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'],
        include: /fonts/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[name].[ext]',
          'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug=false&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false',
        ],
        include: /images/,
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your pattern `/\.s[ac]ss$/i` doesn't meet `css` extension. Try to mark `s` as optional like:

```
test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/i,
```

Or make it cleaner by splitting css as new one from `scss|sass`:

```
test: /\.(s[ac]ss|css)$/i,
```